# ASP.net web services (.asmx) and parallel processing

Tags: iis-7, asmx, parallel-processing

We have written a web service method which returns the Graphic Images generated using the Microsoft WPF (hence STA model). This is working absolutely fine apart from the load balancing.
When the multiple user try to access it at the same time, some of the users gets the Error Message ( Error 503).

Anybody knows how can we improve this to handle multiple client requests (>1000)? Can we use the parallel processing technique to run the threads on different CPU processor (64bit server with 4 core processes)

Comment: Why are you using ASMX in any case? Why not WCF? ASMX is a legacy technology, and shouldn't be used for new development.

Comment: I know but we have to due to some business rquirements. We are planning to migrate to WCF too. Does WCF handles this automatically or do can we do in WCF if ASMX is not possible.

Comment: I don't know, but anything ASMX can do, WCF does better; it then proceeds to do about 10 times more than ASMX...

Comment: OK. what are the settings to handle this in WCF? Any links or samples would be helpful. I'm using asp.net mvc, would MVC AsychController be another options too?